# Is not in (a,b,c) faster than where != a, b, c

Tags: mysql

When writing a query which is faster?

```
SELECT * FROM table where column not in (a,b,c);
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM table where column != a AND column != b AND column != c ;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited my question

Comment: I'm not sure how is it in MySQL but in Oracle "in" and "not in" is just a syntactic sugar for conjunctions and disjunctions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there will be a noticeable difference. Query optimization has very little to do with the syntax of your query and a lot to do with the RDBMS query optimizer. The optimizer pulls apart your queries and optimizes it as it sees fit.

Comment: are there any applications to test on how fast your query is?

Comment: well depends on what level you want to test. If you only need to run a few queries then even adminer or phpMyAdmin should report you query execution time when executing raw SQL queries.